# Local Net Ip Address from a Remote Client in java

Tags: java, ip

Does anyone know how to get the Local Net Ip Address from a Remote Client in java?

thx

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
byte[] ipAddr = addr.getAddress(); // Get IP Address
String hostname = addr.getHostName(); // Get hostname
```

That gets the IP of the machine the code is running on.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean getting  the local IP address of a client running behind NAT, you can only do that with the client's cooperation, meaning you have to send it yourself.

What do you need it for anyway?

Comment: Don't ask why he needs it. People makes a lot of projects. And you know it is very irritating (can't find a better word in English) when they ask you for what you need what you are asking for.

Comment: I don't ask it without a reason. The local IP seems an odd thing to need to know. If we know why he thinks he needs it, we may have better answers.

Comment: Jeje... well..the idea is that I have a server with a web app in a net and the client in another, so.. for example, if the client is in a building A and server in building B, thus the public ip of the building A, I need to know the subnet where the user connect to the app.

Any sugestion?

Comment: But I wonder, why would you need the subnet of the client? I hope it's not for something related to security, because it's not safe.